# Remove bold decoration from symbol

Tags: glossaries, bold

How can I remove the bold decoration from a symbol defined via [glossaries](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/glossaries)? I.e., I need a command to be able to write something like `$\nonbold{\gls{mysymbol}}$`.

The following example illustrates my problem:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{vector}
{
    name={\bm{v}},
    description={vector}
}

\makeglossaries

\newcommand*{\nonbold}[1]{#1} % <-- what goes here?

\begin{document}\noindent
$\nonbold{\gls{vector}}_i$ is the $i$th component of $\gls{vector}$\\
should print as\\
$v_i$ is the $i$th component of $\bm{v}$
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 5):

This is what you can do.

Define your glossary entry as

```
\newglossaryentry{vector}
{
    name={$\bm{v}$},
    description={vector},
    user1={$v$}
}
```

and then use `\glsuseri{vector}` when you want the non-bold version.

MWE

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\newglossaryentry{vector}
{
    name={$\bm{v}$},
    description={vector},
    user1={$v$}
}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\glsuseri{vector}$_i$ is the $i$th component of \gls{vector}

should print as

$v_i$ is the $i$th component of $\bm{v}$

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]